# почему на 1 сцене один и тот же ui работает,а на другой нет

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

public GameObject menuPAUSE;
public float Speed = 10f;
public float JumpForce = 300f;
public GameObject play;
public GameObject part;
//что бы эта переменная работала добавьте тэг "Ground" на вашу поверхность земли
private bool _isGrounded;
private Rigidbody _rb;

```
void Start()
{
    Cursor.visible = false;
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// обратите внимание что все действия с физикой 
// необходимо обрабатывать в FixedUpdate, а не в Update
void FixedUpdate()
{
    MovementLogic();
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        Cursor.visible = true;
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        menuPAUSE.SetActive(true);
    }
}

private void MovementLogic()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    _rb.isKinematic = false;
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    _rb.AddForce(movement * Speed);
}
public void reset()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}
public void exit()
{
    Cursor.visible = true;
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
public void next()
{
    Cursor.visible = true;
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    menuPAUSE.SetActive(false);
}
```